# Internationalization in my WPF application + Exception handling

Tags: .net, wpf, exception, localization, internationalization

I am developing a WPF application making use of PRISM along the way.
I need help on

1. how to add support for 3 different languages.
   could you please suggest any article which tells us how to segregate all the resource strings in a different file, and compile them to achieve the desired result.
2. how to handle exceptions
   I am handling exceptions in a crazy way. though I have exceptions dedicated to each service class / helper class, I still am not able to convey the exact failure message to the end user. The end user has to scroll through the logs to find the exact cause of error.

   Could you please help me to achieve this functionality where in I get to show the user the exact reason for failure of his action, which may happen at a very deeper level within the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could have been two separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be two separate question for both the questions. Anyways you first question is duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795025/localization-in-wpf)

And second question is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336646/mvvm-exception-handling), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228483/where-do-i-catch-exceptions-in-mvvm)